# Storing scripts as a resource

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have a few scripts that I would like my program to work with. However, I would like to know if it is possible for me to store these scripts (eg. batch, javascript, vb scripts etc) in my application as a resource.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: There is no need to add "Delphi - " to your question titles. It's already stated in the tags.

Comment: @BoltClock - Oh yes I know. I put them in the title so I know what question correlates to which language when I go to look at all the questions I have previously asked.

Comment: If you go here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/843935/petersmileyface?tab=questions it displays the tags beneath the titles. Notice some of your other questions with the titles still unmodified; with the tags shown they become quite superfluous.

Comment: I never noticed them, but point taken.

Comment: Tags are only relevant for Stackoverflow's own search though, so repeating in the subject and title is preferable so the answer can be found through google and other proper search engines.

Comment: @Eric, [Stack Overflow automatically puts the primary tag in the title for search engines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72692/33732). For searching on Stack Overflow, you can put your desired tags in brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are components to store arbitrary file/files or string in DFM

For example there are such in rxLib/JediVCL but i believe many VCL libs have one or another kind of DFM Storage component.

For example i used to store Firebird Embedded database in DFM to save it into TEMP and use while running.

However that is akin for manual re-reading file into DFM each time you update it. Rather annoying to say sincerely.

---

One more approach is linking text into resources. You can look into **DUnit** sources to see how it was done. You would also have .rc file included in project, so that it would be compiler into .res when making .exe

This approach is fragile towards ansi/unicode text interpretations.
Frankly, before i found **DUnit** in Delphi XE2 (it was disabled due to IDE bug) i tried to make SF's vanilla DUnit to run there. And i failed - the non-unicode text files linked into resource was totally corrupt when reading with unicode-enabled Delphi.

Look here and there, try both approaches and choose the one that suits you more.

Answer (score 2):

You can store your scripts in resource files. But for example Batch Files need to be file on disk, so you will need to unpack them before working.

Comment: Whereas with Javascript/VBScript, you can extract those resources into strings in memory and execute them directly via the Windows Script Host interface.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good article that explains how you can add almost anything in a resource file and compile it with your application: http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/embed_resources.htm